# @ngrx: Subscription to Store called once it's created

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

My `IStore` is like:

```
export interface IStore {
  user: IUser;
  sources: ISourceRedux;
}
```

In `LoginComponent` I subscribe to `IStore.user`

```
private user$: Observable<IUser>;
private userSub: Subscription;
constructor(private store$: Store<IStore>)
{
    this.user$ = this.store$.select(state => state.user);
}

ngOnInit():void {
    this.userSub = this.user$.subscribe(
        (user: IUser) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/app']);
        },
        (error: any) => {
            this.addAlert(error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

The problem is that the "subscription is called" once it's just created.

Any ideas?

I've these effects:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private _actions$: Actions,
    private _store$: Store<IStore>,
    private _userService: UsersService,
  ) { }

  @Effect({ dispatch: true })
  userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((user: any) => {
          return { type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: user };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return Observable.of({ type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_FAILED', payload: { error: err } });
        })
    );
}
```

and reducers:

```
export class UserReducer {
  private static reducerName = 'USER_REDUCER';

  public static reducer(user = initialUserState(), {type, payload}: Action) {
    if (typeof UserReducer.mapActionsToMethod[type] === 'undefined') {
      return user;
    }

    return UserReducer.mapActionsToMethod[type](user, type, payload);
  }

    // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
    /**
     * Default reducer type. I want all sources.
     */
    public static USER_LOGIN = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN`;

    /**
     * User login success.
     */
    public static USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS`;
    private static userLoginSuccess(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
        return Object.assign(<IUser>{}, sourcesRdx, payload);
    }

    /**
     * User login fails.
     */
    public static USER_LOGIN_FAILED = `${UserReducer.reducerName}_USER_LOGIN_FAILED`;
    private static userLoginFailed(sourcesRdx, type, payload) {
        return Object.assign(<IUser>{}, sourcesRdx, payload);
    }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------

  // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
  private static mapActionsToMethod = {
      [UserReducer.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS]: UserReducer.userLoginSuccess,
      [UserReducer.USER_LOGIN_FAILED]: UserReducer.userLoginFailed,
  };
}
```

Comment: So you want to delay the subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
this.user$
  .skip(1)
  .subscribe(...)
```

if that's the only place where user is initialized in the Store. If that isn't working you can try few other operators to 'wait' for something...

```
this.user$
  .filter(user => user !== "some_inital_different_from_logout_state"
  .subscribe(...)
```

or add `ready` flag to the store

```
this.user$
  .skipUntil(this.store.select('ready'))
  .subscribe(...)
```

#### Update (explanation):

An action `@ngrx/store/init` is dispatched when store initializes and it triggers the first update, since all reducers return their part of the state tree if action didn't match:

```
export function someReducer(state: any, action: Action): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sasxa. I've got it. I'd like to ask you for why this behavior. I don't figure out why this subscription is "activated" if nothing has happened... I mean I've not dispatched any action at these point. I don't know if I'm explained so well...

Comment: Updated the answer with explanation why this is happening

Comment: Nevertheless, `someReducer` is called before my subscription is made, isn't it? So, I understand that a first initialization is called on `someReducer` in order to return de default state, but if the subscription is created after the initialization is made, why the subscription reach a notification?

Comment: Hm.. To be honest I don't know the internal details of Store/Effects, so I'm not sure why it's happening like that. I know how to use them and fix some issues I find along the way (:

Comment: Tho' you have to subscribe before user is logged in (or you won't be able to track login event), and it's logical that first value is `not_logged_in: any`, right?